# Android Studio 3.3.2: device preview switches to another device by choosing landscape layout

Tags: android-studio, designer

I'm working on a portrait layout in the Android Studio designer. I have set the preview device to '10.1 WXGA Tablet'. I also created a landscape layout for the same screen. I want to edit this landscape layout for '10.1 WXGA Tablet'. But whenever I switch from portrait to landscape the preview device changes to the 'Pixel' device. How can I use '10.1 WXGA Tablet' for the landscape layout?

I searched Stackoverflow but I couldn't find a solution. I also tried to find a setting in Android Studio but I can't find something.

Comment: What directory is your tablet layout in?

Comment: @Ge3ng : Portrait layout is in directory 'layout'. Landscape layout is in directory 'layout-land'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to switch devices by default. Unless you create a layout specifically for 10" devices. To do this you need to create a `layout-sw800dp` for tablets and `layout-sw800dp-land` for tablets in landscape.

Take a look at the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#AlternativeResources) for all the different options.

Comment: what do you mean by 'switch devices by default'?

Comment: Android studio when you change between layout directories switches to the default device (Pixel). If you want to support the tablet specifically in your code. you need to specify the layout dimensions the layout supports. Otherwise you need to make sure your layout works on all devices.